# How to change single column of a file to uppercase in linux?

Tags: linux

I have a file with two fields. I need to change the first field values from lowercase to uppercase. Can anyone give me a suggestion on how can I do this?

sample file data

```
e6|VerizonOctoberWB_PromoE7E6
e2|VerizonOctoberWB_UnlimwP_E1E2
e5|VerizonOctoberWB_PromoLI_E5
```

In above sample data I need to change the first field values(e6,e2,e5)

Comment: what have you tried before asking SO?

Comment: Hi @Raswithapokala, welcome to **StackOverflow**, you may take a look to [_"how to ask"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this and future questions. Specially you should provide some [_"research effort"_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), to prove you already tried to solve the problem by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Given your small and poorly formatted sample:

```
cat up
e6|VerizonOctoberWB_PromoE7E6 
e2|VerizonOctoberWB_UnlimwP_E1E2 
e5|VerizonOctoberWB_PromoLI_E5


sed -r 's/^([^|]+)/\U\1\E/g' up
E6|VerizonOctoberWB_PromoE7E6 
E2|VerizonOctoberWB_UnlimwP_E1E2 
E5|VerizonOctoberWB_PromoLI_E5
```

Edit 1: added explanation:
search for and remember everything from beginning of line up to the first separator `|`, replace with `\U`(start upper-casing), `\1` remembered string, `\E` stop upper-casing.

Comment: Can you please explain meaning of this? 
sed -r 's/^([^|]+)/\U\1\E/g' up

Comment: I can. Done. How much regex do you know? ;)

Comment: @Raswithapokala - did this help? Explanation made sense?